# Storybook override import method

Tags: reactjs, storybook

My component 'ReportWrapper' is something like below where it import 'getReportData' which in turn return data async.

```
import { getReportData } from "../dataFecther";

export const ReportWrapper = ({ query }) => { 
  const { data, loading, error } = getReportData({ type: "1", query });
  return (
    <ReportTable
      reportData={data}
      error={error}
    />
  );
```

The way it fetch data may not be suitable for writing Storybook stories.
Is there a way to override this import of 'getReportData' to something like a mock import in stories.

Sample story

```
export default {
  title: "Storybook",
  component: ReportWrapper,
  // More on argTypes: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/argtypes
}; 
const Template = ({ args }) => {
  return (
      <ReportWrapper {...args} />
  );
};

export const First = Template.bind({}); 
First.args = {
  storyName: "First One",
};
```

Comment: what you mean exactly for "override"? Seems to me better approch is to "save" those data in a component and then export them to Storybook

Comment: apologies for confusing I understand 'override' method got a diff meaning in programming world.
I dont have control over current implementation of components, all i need to do is write SB stories for those components.

Similar to mocking data fetch can I pass my custom 'getReportData' method from stories?

Comment: Storybook is meant for checking the UI: therefore ReportWrapper is not an ideal candidate to test as it contains business specific logic.  You can either redesign the component so that data is passed into the component as an arg when it is being consumed. So that when you’re composing it’s story, all you need is to pass mock data into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to use a different `getReportData` in stories. I read this as mocking a module in stories.

I managed to do this using Storybook's [`webpackFinal`](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack) config and to add a webpack plugin - webpack's [`NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/).
Basically you can replace a module in stories using this approach.

You could try this in your storybook config:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /some\/path\/to\/dataFetcher\.js/,
        path.join(__dirname, 'mockedDataFetcher.js')
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. exactly what I want...

Comment: Where does that webpack comes from?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to run a method inside of a component which that method comes from another component.

the first component that wants to take the method from outside

```js
const FirstComponent = ({getReportData}) => {
  const [data,setData]=useState();
  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData=async()=>{
      if(getReportData){
        let response = getReportData();
        if(response.status === 200)
          setData(response.data)
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  })
  return (
    <div>
      {data}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and the second component that to use the first component

```js
const SecondComponent = () => {
  const axiosTest=async()=> {
    let response = await axios.get("ajax/api/..")
    setData(response.data)
}
  return (
    <FirstComponent getReportData={axiosTest} />
  );
};
```